# Access the return value from Orchard WebRequest workflow activity

Tags: orchardcms

I have a workflow that runs when a user submits a form on my site.

As part of the workflow, I also need it to call a web service and display the return value in a message via the Notify activity.

I have added a WebRequest activity to the workflow which connects OK, but how do I access the return value from the web service?

Any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the response of `WebRequest` activity in the activities next to it simply by:

```
{Workflow.State:WebRequestResponse}
```

FYI, this activity has two outcomes `Success` and `Error`, be sure to handle these two outcomes, see the following photos:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Brilliant - had a problem with my web service originally, but fixed that and this works like a charm. Thanks!

Comment: hello, am using orchard beta2. trying to implement the workflows. i donot see any documents are examples available. and cannot implement the above as my orchard version is new...please share some sample code if you guys worked on latest version of orchard workflow.

Answer (score 0):

This might help people who looking to get started with the orchard the latest version of workflow.
https://github.com/OrchardCMS/OrchardCore/issues/1673